# How to know what date my app was published in Windows Phone Store?

Tags: windows-phone

As stated in the subjects, this information seems to be missing from the Dev Center; all I could do is to get an approximate date which is the date of the first download of the app.

Does anyone know a better (official) way to get this information?

P.S. the "Published on" information in the app Details page is the date of the last update you published not the first time the app was published in the Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no such info on this (maybe you can find out only if you are going to browse your DL history graphs).
To view this info open your app page on the Store on your Windows Phone Device, you'll find there the info 'originally released'.

Best regards,

Manuel

Comment: Thanks... the looking in the Store app was a great hint.

Comment: @TheBlueSky if you find out another way/place feel free to share it